# Send CDO email using Outlook through excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code for emailing using CDO from internet - but I keep getting the message " The transport failed to connect to the server"

I have tried various setting changes for server exchange but no luck.

```````
`````
strSubject = "Results from Excel Spreadsheet"
strFrom = "jceast7@hotmail.com"   '"rdube02@gmail.com"
strTo = "jceast7@hotmail.com"     '"rdube02@gmail.com"
strCc = ""
strBcc = ""
strBody = "The total results for this quarter are: "   '& Str

'STEP 3
'The next section of code is where you will configure CDO to use any
 external SMTP server to send the email.


Set CDO_Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
On Error GoTo Error_Handling

Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
CDO_Config.Load -1

Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields

With SMTP_Config
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")
= "Microsoft Exchange"  '"smtp.hotmail.com"   '"smtp.gmail.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")
= 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")
= "jceast7@hotmail.com"     '"email@website.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")
= "123456"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") 
= 25
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
.Update
End With

With CDO_Mail
Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
End With
``````
```````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send mail with VBA using CDO // Mail Server is Exchange with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597467/how-to-send-mail-with-vba-using-cdo-mail-server-is-exchange-with-proxy)

Comment: I don't know about Hotmail but with GMail you gave to log in and go to Options and tick allow unknown mail programs (eg CDO) to use GMail.

Comment: I am searching for the options to connect CDO and outlook / Hotmail - nothing yet

Answer (score 2):

```
 " The transport failed to connect to the server"
```

That error means that u need to login in your account on website (Google or whatever)
and select "Allow external progams to use the email" (something like that) , it worked for me , I was in the same place as you!

Comment: I am logged into my Microsoft account.  I go to outlook, File Options and I cannot find anything at this point that says "Allow external programs to use email" or similar.  Frustrating at this point

Comment: It is not in Outlook , you need to log into your Server account (Microsoft Login for example)

Comment: I really appreciate the help - I do not know how to my server account - but I will google it and see what I find.